# SAS script works via EG, but fails in linux

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am trying to go over set and get the `path` of a file. Then, I want to open the file and get another set out of it.

My problem is that my script `works` without any issues when executed via Enterprise Guide, but `fails` if executed via command line.

> WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro GET_DATA not resolved.

Seems like my `path` variable is not set and my macro is not executed when I run it via command line.

```
data _null_;
    set files_to_parse; 
    count + 1;
    call execute('%get_data('||path||', '||count||')');
run;
```

Here I am trying to instantiate an excel as a library

```
%macro get_data(path, cnt);
/* Get current iteration of excel spreadsheet */
libname xl XLSX "&path.";
%mend get_data;
```

Comment: Order of operations. Run the macro and then call it.

Comment: Is you EG session connecting to the same Linux server as you are using when you submit the code from the command line (i.e. batch submit)?  If you start a new EG session and submit the code, does it work the first time you run it?  If %get_data is an autocall macro, you can turn on `options mautolocdisplay;` to see where its source code is stored.  Then you  would need to make sure the directory is in your sasautos path when you submit the batch job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have defined the macro before trying to use it.  Perhaps with EG your program worked because you had previously compiled the macro.

Answer (score -1):

The error is that `%get_data` is not compiled, not that it's not resolving the path.

It's hard to say why with the information you gave us, but since you see a difference running in EG vs in command line, I suspect you either have the macro compiled as part of an autoexec process flow in EG, or you have an autocall macro library that's not properly set up through the command line config file.  Talk to your SAS Admin if you don't know what these things mean.

Comment: is there any way to work around this problem without involving anyone?

Comment: You'd only need to involve someone if you don't know how to check the things I mention above.  But if you don't ... you need help.

Comment: Looks like you have the code for the macro in your post.  Just add the definition to your program before you attempt to call it.

Comment: Not sure I'd recommend that, because if OP is a SAS user in a shop that expects you to be using common macros or something of that sort, adding the definition to their code is the wrong answer.

Comment: @Tom, that was exactly the case. Did not know that the order in SAS matters (OO programming background). Please post it as an answer